# import .py файла в Python

Tags: python, импорт

У меня есть 2 файла .ру . В Одном из них основной код, в другом ифнормация. Мне нужно импортировать файл с информацией в основной код. Как мне это сделать?

`import Info.py`

или

`from Info.py import *`

не работает. Подскажите, как это сделать? Раньше вроде так работало, а сейчас нет. Вопрос может показаться глупым, но я правда не понимаю, как импортировать подобные файлы.

P.S Данные файлы содержатся в одной папке

Прикладываю скрин с файлами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `import Info` же

Comment: Нет, так не работает

Comment: Почему не работает?

Comment: Потому и не работает, пишет:    import Info.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Info.py'; 'Info' is not a package

Comment: import info - Если ты хочешь импортировать весь файл
from Info import * - Если импортируешь все функции из файла

Comment: Так я ж и говорю — нужно писать не `import Info.py`, а `import Info`, это будет работать

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Info.py'; 'Info' is not a package`

Comment: Не пишите никакого `Info.py`, пишите только `Info` без всяких py

Comment: Я и пишу Info. Не работает. Файлы в одной директории. Я потому и задался этим вопросом, так как раньше всё работало, сейчас нет

Comment: Почему не работает? Строчка `import Info` абсолютно точно не может выдавать ту ошибку, которую вы показали.

Comment: Да, действительно работает... Но только в другом проекте, в моём выдаёт ошибку, а Pycharm не находит данный файл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вам не нужно писать разрешение .py после названия файлов при импорте функций из них**

Соответственно, замените `import Info.py` на `import Info`

И `from Info.py import *` на `from Info import *`

Проверьте, что рабочая директория файла, в который вы импортируете функции совпадает с директорией, в которой находится импортируемый файл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если честно, не понимаю. Пишет ошибку...

Comment: какую ошибку???

Comment: @GreenPy Прикрепил изображение. Проверьте - файлы у вас находятся в одной и той же директории?

Comment: Вижу, всё работает, но только в новом проекте, в моём же ничего не работает

Comment: @GreenPy Дайте, пожалуйста, больше информации. Прикрепите скрин структуры хранения файлов проекта.

Comment: Я изменил статью вопроса, посмотрите, там есть скрин

Comment: @GreenPy Попробуйте перенести все файлы из директории Zh-bot в корневую директорию проекта и заново запустить код.

Comment: Да, всё заработало. Хотя странно, Python вроде должен искать файл в той же папке, где находится сам файл. Спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: Рабочая директория при запуске скрипта Bot.py - корневая директория проекта. Python пытается найти Info.py в той же корневой директории, но у него этого сделать не получается, так как Info.py находится в директории Zh-Bot.